# Adding More IPs to a Netcard on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip-address, route, nic

How do I add more IP addresses to a network card on Linux? Do I use the route command?

It's Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? I don't get it?

Comment: @sciurus, I disagree. If we're going to do that, then what's the point of serverfault.com? Besides, a quarter of the time we do searches on Google these days, we get spam blogs, or a query in a forum where no one has ever given out an answer, or ExpertExchange (gah!), or advice from like 2007. No thanks. I'll stick with the stack* sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you mean you want to add secondary ip ?

```
   $ sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
     auto eth0
     iface eth0 inet static
      address x.x.x.x
      netmask x.x.x.x
      network x.x.x.x
      gateway x.x.x.x
      broadcast x.x.x.x

     auto eth0:1
      iface eth0:1 inet static
      address x.x.x.x
      netmask x.x.x.x
      network x.x.x.x
      broadcast x.x.x.x

   $ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Can you expand on this? I mean, what about the changes I need to do to whatever else is already in /etc/network/interfaces by default?

Comment: on /etc/network/interfaces, the default is only 1 device (eth0/etch1/ethX) so you need to add more if you want to add secondary ip, i updated the sample above.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the new style:

```
ip address add 192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0
```

Or the old style:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
```